# "list index out of range" exception (Python3)

Tags: python, list

I keep getting a list index out of range exception when I check the length of the list a. The error pops up for either the `if` or `elif` part of the second `if` statement, depending on what the user inputs. I know that when the user input is split the list is created correctly because I print it out... So I'm a little lost about why I'm getting that error.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
            for line in sys.stdin:
                    s = line.strip()
                    if not s: break
                    if (str(s) is "quit") == True: quit()
                    elif (str(s) is "quit") == False:
                            a = s.split()
                            print(a)
                            if (len(a) == 2) == True: first(a)
                            elif (len(a) == 3) == True: first(a)
                            else: print("Invalid Input. Please Re-enter.")
```

The first method is: (The methods it calls in the if statement just print things out at the moment)

```
def first(self, a = list()):
            word = a[0]

            if word is ls:
                    ls(a[1])           
            elif word is format:
                    form(a[1])        # EDIT: was format
            elif word is reconnect:
                    reconnect(a[1])
            elif word is mkfile:
                    mkfile(a[1])
            elif word is mkdir:
                    mkdir(a[1])
            elif word is append:
                    append(a[1], a[2])                               
            elif word is delfile:
                    delfile(a[1])
            elif word is deldir:
                    deldir(a[1])
            else:
                    print("Invalid Prompt. Please Re-enter.")
```

Other methods:

```
    def reconnect(one = ""):
            print("Reconnect")

    def ls(one = ""):
            print("list")

    def mkfile(one = ""):
            print("make file")

    def mkdir(one = ""):
            print("make drive")

    def append(one = "", two = ""):
            print("append")

    def form(one = ""):
            print("format")

    def delfile(one = ""):
            print("delete file")

    def deldir(one = ""):
            print("delete directory")

    def quit():
            print("quit")
            sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: What is first ?

Comment: It's another method I've created. The error pops up before it's called so I just figured it's not relevant when fixing this error.

Comment: What you are trying to do with. ** if (str(s) is "quit") == True:**

Comment: If the user enters "quit" the system quits... you know you're not really helping answer the question

Comment: Your code is ok. The issue here is not what you pasted. Please post the `first` function

Comment: Still can't see the issue here. Can you past the error message. ?

Comment: What are you typing in to the input to get the error?

Comment: What's the print(a) outcome ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be the definition of `first()`.  You invoke it as a function:

```
if (len(a) == 2) == True: first(a)
elif (len(a) == 3) == True: first(a)
```

But you define it as a method:

```
def first(self, a = list()):
```

The array of command and argument gets put into `self` and `a` is always an empty list which you attempt to index and fail.  Also, you shouldn't use a mutable type like `list()` as a default value unless you're certain what you are doing.  I suggest simply:

```
def first(a):
```

As far as your `__main__` code goes, simplify:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    for line in sys.stdin:
        string = line.strip()

        if not string:
            break

        if string == "quit":
            quit()

        tokens = string.split()

        length = len(tokens)

        if 2 <= length <= 3:
            first(tokens)
        else:
            print("Invalid Input. Please Re-enter.")
```

Comment: for the `first` method, if `word` is append then there should be 2 inputs after it so the I think it's best to use a list instead of a string; i.e. since you don't know how many words will be inputted

Answer (score 0):

### Real issue:

To solve your error you have to **remove** the `self` parameter of the `first` function

```
def first(a=list())
```

Basically the **self** is only used for object orientation creating methods. 
Function like yours can't use self otherwise you will passing the first parameter to self not to a which you want to.

My second issue I can point out is that, You are trying to compare using `is` between a **string** and a **function**.

```
 def first(a = list()):
        word = a[0]

        if word is "ls":
                ls(a[1])           
        elif word is "format":
                format(a[1])
        elif word is "reconnect":
                reconnect(a[1])
        elif word is "mkfile":
                mkfile(a[1])
        elif word is "mkdir":
                mkdir(a[1])
        elif word is "append":
                append(a[1], a[2])                               
        elif word is "delfile":
                delfile(a[1])
        elif word is "deldir":
                deldir(a[1])
        else:
                print("Invalid Prompt. Please Re-enter.")
```

### Extra

The `is` function on built in operations in Python. `is` compare the equity of the objects.

But this expression:

```
if (str(s) is "quit") == True:
```

Can be simpler like:

```
if str(s) == "quit":
```

Or:

```
if str(s) is "quit":
```

The `== True` is meaningless either `== False` you can use `not` more pythonicly.

Comment: Note that ``str(s) == "quit"`` and ``str(s) is "quit"`` are fundamentally different comparisons. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce

Comment: OK, but why am I getting an error when the user enters something else like "delfile oirgorhgoe" (which will ultimately delete file called oirgorhgoe) and the length of the list a (after s is split) with "delfile oirgorhgoe" in it is checked?

Comment: @GabbyFreeland just tested your code and I think the first function is the issue here.

Comment: @GabbyFreeland can you please post the error message here ?

Comment: I've just posted the first function. The error was `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\COMPSCI 340\CS340 A2\TinyDOS.py", line 10, in <module>
    class TinyDOS():
  File "E:\COMPSCI 340\CS340 A2\TinyDOS.py", line 74, in TinyDOS
    if (len(a) is 2): first(a)
  File "E:\COMPSCI 340\CS340 A2\TinyDOS.py", line 43, in first
    word = a[0]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Even though the strings are compared incorrectly, how does that address the error?

Comment: ok, I'm still getting an error for the `word = a[0]` part in the first function though

Comment: @GabbyFreeland have you changed the function signature? Pls tell me the outcome of print(a)

Comment: That part it working now, it's just saying none of the other methods I've defined are actually defined, even though they are...

Comment: if I enter `format irughwie` then `a` will print as `['format', 'irughwie']`, then I'll get an error when the format method is called `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\COMPSCI 340\CS340 A2\TinyDOS.py", line 10, in <module>
    class TinyDOS():
  File "E:\COMPSCI 340\CS340 A2\TinyDOS.py", line 72, in TinyDOS
    if (len(a) is 2): first(a)
  File "E:\COMPSCI 340\CS340 A2\TinyDOS.py", line 48, in first
    form(a[1])
NameError: name 'form' is not defined`